# How can I locate orphanages in Bond, Madison, Cole counties in Illinois from 1930 to 1937?

Tags: adoption

Cleo McCain was put in orphanage by Henry McCain (father) sometime between 1930 and 1936.  He was removed by foster parents Oscar & Fredia Suess by 1937.  They lived in Bond County, Illinois in 1935.  But I have no idea what county in southern Illinois his father was in when Cleo was put in orphanage.

Comment: I have used censuses to identify institutions of various kinds. The residents are typically identified as inmates rather that lodgers or boarders. The address column or the ED description may include the institution name. If not otherwise named, the ages of the inmates would hint at the kind of institution. The intervals between censuses might miss any that were ephemeral. Are you sure your Cleo was in an institution rather than fostered out?